# Bitsadmin Doesn't Work with Some Websites (Windows 7 32-bit)

Tags: rest, windows-7, command-prompt, imagedownload

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate (32-bit), and tried to download this photo:

`bitsadmin /transfer /download "https://www.techrepublic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/powershell.jpg" c:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\photo.jpg`

This is the error I received:

```
DISPLAY: '/download' TYPE: DOWNLOAD STATE: ERROR
PRIORITY: NORMAL FILES: 0 / 1 BYTES: 0 / UNKNOWN
Unable to complete transfer.
ERROR FILE:    https://www.techrepublic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/powershell.jpg -> c:\Users\MySccount\Desktop\photo.jpg
ERROR CODE:    0x80072f7d - An error occurred in the secure channel support
ERROR CONTEXT: 0x00000005 - The error occurred while the remote file was being processed.
```

How to download this image using bitsadmin on Windows 7 (32-bit)?

Please note that I even used VBScipt and Powershell, and it didn't work, ether.